# XMLからの正規化した行の出力

Tags: xpath, xsl, xslt

次の様なXMLがあります．

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sect>
    <p>  donguri korokoro 
        donburiko    </p>
    <p>koike ni hamatte saa         taihen</p>
    <p>dojyou      mo  detekite    konnnitiwa</p>
    <p>   bocchann isshoni     asobimasho    </p>
</sect>
```

これから`<p>`を単位としてホワイトスペースを正規化して行にし

```
donguri korokoro donburiko
koike ni hamatte saa taihen
dojyou mo detekite konnnitiwa
bocchann isshoni asobimasho
```

というテキスト出力を得たいです．最終行には改行はなくてかまいません．
今まではこんなスタイルシートを作っていましたが、

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="sect/p">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() ne last()">
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xsl:for-eachがあったり、xsl:ifがあったりといまいちスッキリしません．もっと単純に（一発で）結果を得られるようにはできないものでしょうか？スタイルシートはXSLT 2.0以上で結構です．

以上 よろしくお願いします．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normalize-space を施した 要素p の文字列値のシーケンス に対して， 
separator で改行を指定して分割する方法があります。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="sect/p/normalize-space(.)" separator="&#x0A;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XPath 2.0ではパス式に関数が記述できるところがミソなのですね！

Answer (score 0):

質問のスタイルシートに

```
<xsl:if test="position() ne last()">
  <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

という処理ありますので、metropolisさんの回答にあるテンプレート

```
<xsl:template match="sect/p">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(), '&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

を

```
<xsl:template match="sect/p">
  <xsl:value-of select="if (position() eq last()) then normalize-space(.) else concat(normalize-space(.), '&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

のように if式を使うようにすると、最終行に改行が付かないようにすることもできます。